# How do I target another database with tracker-enabled-dbcontext

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, tracker-enabled-dbcontext

I'm trying to implement the  tracker-enabled-dbcontext package from the [documentaion](https://tracker-enabled-dbcontext.bilal-fazlani.com) and [tracker-enabled-dbcontext git repository](https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext)
But I'm unable to change save changes to target a different database. I've modified my SaveChanges

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork {}
public class MacsAuditDbContext : TrackerEnabledDbContext.TrackerContext {}
```

in MyDBContext

```
public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            DateTime nowAuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry<DomainEntity>> changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<DomainEntity>();
            if (changeSet != null)
            {
                foreach (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry<DomainEntity> entry in changeSet)
                {
                    switch (entry.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Added:
                            entry.Entity.Created = nowAuditDate;
                            entry.Entity.Modified = nowAuditDate;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            entry.Entity.Modified = nowAuditDate;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            using (MacsAuditDbContext db = new MacsAuditDbContext())
            {
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
```

in my startup class

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            AuthConfig.Register(app);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .UseSqlServerStorage("MacsAuditDbContext");
                }
    }
```

But I am still unable to save audit logs to the target(secondary) database. my Domain entires saving my primary DB but not audit logs.
Do I want to pass MyDBContext to MacsAuditDbContext? Or Am I doing something wrong? please help me.

Comment: Are you aware that you're using a library that hasn't been updated for 2 years and targets EF 6 classic?

Comment: yes. at this moment I have to use this. we are using this our own git fork

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try leveraging [`OnAuditLogGenerated`](https://tracker-enabled-dbcontext.bilal-fazlani.com/events/) event. Something along this lines:

```cs
public sealed class MyDBContext : TrackerContext
{
    public MyDBContext ()
    {
        OnAuditLogGenerated += SaveToAnotherDb;
    }

    private void SaveToAnotherDb(object? sender, AuditLogGeneratedEventArgs args)
    {
        var auditLog = args.Log;

        using (MacsAuditDbContext db = new MacsAuditDbContext())
        {
            db.AuditLog.Add(auditLog);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        //skips saving to local database
        args.SkipSavingLog = true;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        OnAuditLogGenerated -= SaveToAnotherDb;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```